# Call same function on two different objects in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have two unrelated objects (3rd party API) that have the some of the same properties. I'd like one helper method to call that will extract the data from the properties and build a `NSDate` object but `theObject.valueForKey` does not seem to work.

I've tried this function signature `func foo<T: NSObject where T: NSObjectProtocol>(record: T) -> NSDate? { ... }` but no luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @Hasya your edit adds noise, the tags are not relevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what protocols are for:

```
class ClassOne {
    var dateInfo: String = ""
}

class ClassTwo {
    var otherDateInfo: String = ""
}

protocol DateBuildingProtocol {
    func buildDateFromDateInfo() -> NSDate
}

extension ClassOne: DateBuildingProtocol {
    func buildDateFromDateInfo() -> NSDate {
        // do something with self.dateInfo
        return NSDate()
    }
}

extension ClassTwo: DateBuildingProtocol {
    func buildDateFromDateInfo() -> NSDate {
        // do something with self.otherDateInfo
        return NSDate()
    }
}
```

Protocols give you the power of multiple-inheritance that some other languages have.  Basically you declare a method that both classes should have, and implement the method on each class to use the specific variable you need.

Comment: Just an osservation, why do you replicate under extension syntax the same protocol func? extension ClassTwo: DateBuildingProtocol {} is not enough?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano `extension ClassTwo: DateBuildingProtocol {}` would cause an error, since `ClassTwo` does not conform to `DateBuildingProtocol`.  I assume the implementation of `buildDateFromDateInfo` would be different for each class, as the OP says he's working with two unrelated types with potentially different variable names.

Comment: I think the variable names are the same, see the question title (“call same function”). But that’s just a special case of your general solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get a type that will apply to both classes and expose the common property, you can use a protocol and implement the protocol using an extension:

```
class Foo {
    let name = "foo"
}

class Bar {
    let name = "bar"
}

protocol HasName {
    var name: String { get }
}

extension Foo: HasName {}
extension Bar: HasName {}

func getName(x: HasName) -> String {
    return x.name
}

getName(Foo()) // "foo"
getName(Bar()) // "bar"
```