# Swift AnyObject variable, using or to chain downcast (as) to access different classes' properties

Tags: swift

I have two classes, depending which game the user is going to play ("passedTitle" in code). I want to use the same view controller because the whole logic is similar.

So at global I defined a variable `questionAll : AnyObject`. Then at `viewdidload()` I assign it to either `Trivia()` instance or `Diy()` based on `passedTitle` value. However, I can only access this instance's specific properties by downcasting using `as?` with `if` optional chain.

I need to use this instance and access properties in many different functions and because I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
if let A = B as? Trivia || Diy { code here is same }
```

but obviously it's wrong and I can't find an answer online.

Below is some of the related code:

```
var questionAll : AnyObject

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //based on the game title decide which game played
    if passedTitle == "Trivia" {
        questionAll = Trivia()
    }else if passedTitle == "Diy" {
        questionAll = Diy()
    }

    //calculate the total grades
    if let questionAllInstance = questionAll as? Trivia{
        for singlePoint in questionAllInstance.answers["level\(level)"]!{
            let sumGrade = singlePoint.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
            totalGrade += sumGrade
        }
    }
    if let questionAllInstance = questionAll as? Diy{
        for singlePoint in questionAllInstance.answers["level\(level)"]!{
            let sumGrade = singlePoint.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
            totalGrade += sumGrade
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call same function on two different objects in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871449/call-same-function-on-two-different-objects-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `AnyObject` is a code smell, usually you only use a limited set of objects to pass to your class, and by looking at the code from the question, the set holds only two types: `Trivia`, and `Diy`. So why not placing them both under the same umbrella?

```
protocol Question {
    var answers: [String:[Int]] { get } // or the actual dictionary type from your code
}
```

You can then just simply declare the protocol conformance for the two classes:

```
extension Trivia: Question {
    // nothing to do, Trivia should already have an answers property
}

extension Diy: Question {
    // nothing to do, Trivia should already have an answers property
}
```

, and use it in your VC:

```
var questionAll : Question?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //based on the game title decide which game played
    if passedTitle == "Trivia" {
        questionAll = Trivia()
    }else if passedTitle == "Diy" {
        questionAll = Diy()
    }

    //calculate the total grades
    if let questionAllInstance = questionAll,
        let points = questionAllInstance.answers["level\(level)"] {
        for singlePoint in points { // I replaced the forced unwrap to the optional binding above
            let sumGrade = singlePoint.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
            totalGrade += sumGrade
        }
    }
```

Now if you're really keen to the `AnyObject` declaration, or you are forced to use it for other reasons, you can use a `switch` to reduce the duplication in the original code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //based on the game title decide which game played
    if passedTitle == "Trivia" {
        questionAll = Trivia()
    }else if passedTitle == "Diy" {
        questionAll = Diy()
    }

    let answers: TypeOfAnswers? // an optional of what the `answers` property is
    switch questionAll {
    case let trivia as Trivia: answers = trivia.answers
    case let diy as Diy: answers = diy.answers
    default: answers = nil
    }

    if let points = answers?["level\(level)"] {
        for singlePoint in points {
            let sumGrade = singlePoint.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
            totalGrade += sumGrade
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you could use a local function to process the answers:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //based on the game title decide which game played
    if passedTitle == "Trivia" {
        questionAll = Trivia()
    }else if passedTitle == "Diy" {
        questionAll = Diy()
    }

    func process(answers: TypeOfAnswers) {
        if let points = questionAllInstance.answers["level\(level)"] {
            for singlePoint in points { // I replaced the forced unwrap to the optional binding above
                let sumGrade = singlePoint.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
                totalGrade += sumGrade
            }
        }
    }

    switch questionAll {
    case let trivia as Trivia: process(answers: trivia.answers)
    case let diy as Diy: process(answers: diy.answers)
    default: break
    }
```